# Assembly - why do we need to move certain values from register to another register (f.ex., mov si, ax) during a write operation?

Tags: assembly, x86, computer-science

I have been following a tutorial series and I have come to the part where we write to files. Here is a part of the code that writes to files, as it has been shown in the tutorial:

```
mov ah, 3d
mov al, 1
mov dx, 150
int 21
mov si, ax
mov ah, 40
mov bx, si
mov cx, 0d
mov dx, 175
int 21
int 20
```

The author does explain everything step by step, it's just that he does not explain every line in an equally understandable way. I understand the inital part, that ah, 3d & al, 1 opens the file and sets up the stage for writing while dx, 150 targets the specific file, but I am not sure about the following

For example, why do we move ax to si, why can not the value remain in ax? Why do we further proceed to move si to bx - why can not the value remain in si? Thank you for any clarification... I am aware that this is a noobie question but it would help me a lot to have this clarified. Thanks.

Comment: Because that's where the function called by `int 21h` will look for it.  This is called a "calling convention" or ABI: an agreement between caller and callee which arg goes where.  See http://www.ctyme.com/rbrown.htm for the 16-bit BIOS / DOS system-call interface.

Comment: Also, you left out the `h` suffix to make the interrupt numbers hex constants.  It's 21h.

Comment: `int 21h` isn't magic, it's just one of the "jump/call" instructions making CPU to start to execute different code. That code was programmed by your DOS vendor. And that vendor decided, that his code will check `ah` for some value, like `40h`, and if it will find it there, it will write data to file handle `bx` of length `cx` at address in `ds:dx`. The `si` contains copy of file handle, probably for later parts of tutorial, not needed for this particular call. Also you can't do `ah=40h` without modifying `ax`, it's same register, just different bit range. Other OS may[/will] act differently.

Comment: Thank you Peter Cordes / Ped7g, that is the explanation I needed to understand what is going on

Comment: BTW. That `si` (I guess even the `bx` will be preserved by `40h` service) file handle will be handy to call `close file` service. That's probably not needed with such short app which terminates correctly right away (although I wouldn't risk that back in ~DOS v3.x era), but if you would for example loop infinitely later in app without closing the file or calling fflush, on real PC AT with DOS the content of file would be most likely left somewhere in cache not written to disk, and lost after restarting machine. Don't spend much time learning `int 21h` services, it's DOS-only, just have fun :).

Comment: The example code after the first `int 21` could have been | `mov bx,ax` | `mov ah,40` | ... .

Comment: @PeterCordes - no `h` suffix, maybe the book is using debug.com as a crude assembler? The offsets are hard coded, not symbols.

Comment: Oh right, I forgot about `debug.com` assuming all numbers are hex.  If you're doing that, use a different assembler.  `debug.com` is generally considered obsolete and not very user friendly.

Comment: On a side note the debug.com tutorial being referenced is this [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NM5HxI-AaRY)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calling convention for interrupt 21h "system calls" has the arguments and return codes in specific registers. E.g. the selector of which type of call to make is in register `ah`. For the Open File call (3dh), `al` is the sharing mode and `ds:dx` is the pointer to the filename. It returns its result in `ax`. But `ax` overlaps `ah` and `al` and in order to do the write call, 40h must be put in `ah` as that is the selector for the Write call. The file handle returned in `ax` must be preserved, which involves either writing it to memory or moving it to a register which is guaranteed to be preserved across the call.

You can see documentation on the `int 21h` calling conventions e.g. [here](http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html), or in [Ralph Brown's interrupt list](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/int-21.htm).  See also other x86 docs in the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki.

Comment: Thank you Zalman, I'm seeing it more clearly now. I see there are a lot of things to learn here, so I'll be posting some more if I come across problems again :)